# Fatal Error when downloading repository

Tags: github, gitlab

When I put this command on the command line it shows following error.

```
$ git pull origin branchname
remote: Counting objects: 30138, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (21286/21286), done.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly2.97 MiB | 511.00 KiB/s
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. First, read this [wiki about this site](www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow) Probably you will need to edit this question in order to get an answer, provide some code or be more specific about what is your problem and how did you get it.

Comment: That's typically caused by a networking issue. Wait and try again or contact the provider for your remote repository

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.. issue was resolved